# How should we tag questions on regional dialects of Spanish?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

We currently have tags like [mexican-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-spanish), [nicaraguan-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicaraguan-spanish) and [central-american-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-american-spanish) but also ones like [spain](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain) and [valencia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valencia). We should probably standardize this. Which form should we use for tags referring to a specific dialect of Spanish?

Comment: FWIW, English L&U has tags for `american-english`, `british-english`, `australian-english`, `irish-english`, `indian-english`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @SergioCinos' answer (as well as @JoulSauron's answer to my [duplicate question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/232/12)), I have renamed the following tags:

- [mexican-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-spanish) → [mexico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexico)
- [colombian-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colombian-spanish) → [colombia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colombia)
- [nicaraguan-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicaraguan-spanish) &rar; [nicaragua](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicaragua)
- [chilean-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chilean-spanish) → [chile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chile)
- [costa-rican-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costa-rican-spanish) → [costa-rica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costa-rica)
- [peruvian-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peruvian-spanish) → [peru](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peru)
- [panamanian-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panamanian-spanish) → [panama](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panama)

Additionally, [central-american-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-american-spanish) had only a single question, which I re-tagged to [latin-america](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-america) (I know it's not quite as precise, but it seems close enough for a single question, no?)

I have not yet done anything with [standard-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-spanish) (see [meta question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/235/12)) or [neutral-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutral-spanish), as I'm not sure what we should do with it.

Comment: By now there might be just one question of [tag:latin-america], but as soon as the site grows, it's very likely that we'll need a [tag:central-america] tag.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use tags with just the country name, like 'spain', 'mexico' and so on. Using the suffix '-spanish' looks redundant to me, as this is a site focused on Spanish language.

Technically, it is possible to have different Spanish dialects in the same country (this is, at least, [true for Spain](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectos_del_castellano_en_Espa%C3%B1a)). Although I find questions related to "internal" dialects interesting, I doubt they are common enough to deserve their own tags.

Comment: This would allow us to avoid `spanish-spanish` for the Spanish from Spain :)

Comment: It's also possible to have dialectal features shared between multiple countries such as Rioplatense / River Plate Spanish and Cono sur / Southern Cone. Even the RAE uses such terminology. It might be interesting to find their list.