# How shall we tag regional questions?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should we tag questions on regional dialects of Spanish?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/how-should-we-tag-questions-on-regional-dialects-of-spanish)

While going through all our tags, for the English/Spanish tag conversion, it became clear that we need a standard way to tag questions related to regional variances of Spanish.  Currently, the majority of our tags follow this pattern:

- [mexican-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-spanish)
- [peruvian-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peruvian-spanish)
- etc..

But we have a few odd-balls:

- [spain](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain)
- [argentina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/argentina)
- [venezuela](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venezuela)

And we have a couple more general tags:

- [latin-america](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-america)
- [central-american-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-american-spanish)

We ought to come up with a standardized way to tag these questions.  We could use simply the name of the country/region ([mexico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexico), [latin-america](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-america)), or we could use the (currently) more common [xyz-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xyz-spanish), or after our tag overhaul, perhaps [espanol-de-xyz](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espanol-de-xyz).

Answer (score 1):

There was already a [question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/how-should-we-tag-questions-on-regional-dialects-of-spanish) about this, and I would go with [this answer](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/207/106:):

> I suggest to use tags with just the country name, like 'spain',
>   'mexico' and so on. Using the suffix '-spanish' looks redundant to me,
>   as this is a site focused on Spanish language.

So, for sure I wouldn't use "spanish" affix to avoid redundancy. If this site were about Canada, it'd be logical to use [quebec-french](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quebec-french) and [vancuver-english](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vancuver-english), which is not the case.

Now, it remains how to call the regional variances. For making tagging simpler and easier, I would use just the name of the region or country (peru), instead of the name of the variety (peruvian):

- [spain](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain)
- [argentina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/argentina)
- [peru](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peru)
- [mexico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexico)
- [oaxaca](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oaxaca)
- [latin-america](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-america)
- [central-america](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-america)

Comment: Good call, thanks for pointing out the other question.