# Do we need the standard-spanish tag?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

The [standard-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-spanish) tag's description reads:

> Questions seeking correct usage, spelling, etc. as endorsed by the Real Academia Española, the body officially charged with the maintenance and development of the Spanish language.

We also have [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae):

> Royal Spanish Academy (Spanish: Real Academia Española, RAE) is the official royal institution responsible for regulating the Spanish language.

Do we need both?  Can [standard-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-spanish) be merged into [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae)?

Comment: Actually the tag wiki for [tag:rae] is a bad tag wiki according to [the Stack Exchange standards which say they shouldn't just be definitions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/) but tell us which kinds of questions the tag should be used for. It's possible that there are questions asking about the academy itself, the many editions of its dictionaries and other publications, or its previous historical standards rather than its most current one, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take on this:

> Do we need the standard-spanish tag?

No, this entire site is already about standard spanish. Rather, you could use tags for other varieties, that could work. But having this tag would mean to tag 90% of the questions with it: quite useless.

---

I'm also against tags like [novice-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novice-spanish). They don't work very well.

Comment: I have removed the [standard-spanish] tag from the 7 questions that had it, and where appropriate, added new tags.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the [standard-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-spanish) tag is a bit redundant in a Spanish Language "forum" (or whatever you classify SO as).  Perhaps the tag could be changed to something like [basic-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic-spanish) or [novice-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novice-spanish) so that we at least know the level of the question.

The [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) should really only be used if the question questions a rule of RAE, in my opinion

Comment: I don't like to distinguish basic, novice or advanced Spanish. Spanish is always the same, and the questions and answers should be always in "Spanish", regardless of the expertise of the user.